# Code placement in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've added the code below to each of the 3 sheets in my Excel 2003 template (Book.xlt).
The code in each sheet is identical; which got me wondering: can I place the code in one place so it is available to each sheet.
I tried putting it in ThisWorkBook and in a User Module - neither worked.

**The Code**

```
'=====================================================================
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
'- Used with conditional format so selected row is shaded yellow:
'        =AND(CELL("row")=ROW(),UPPER(cel_HighlightRow)="Y")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
'=====================================================================
Private Sub cmdGrabTable_Click()
'- Select table with 1 click.
   Range("tbl_1Main").Select
End Sub  'cmdGrabTable SortData
'=====================================================================
```

Regards, huon

Comments added 25.Jul.13 at 02:50 (Canberra, Australia)
Hello

1. Notes:
   Each of the 3 sheets has a cmdGrabTable button, and a tbl_1Main (ie in Sheet2 it is tbl_1Main, not tbl_2Main).
   The conditional format is applied to each of the 3 tables.
2. Application.ScreenUpdating = True: 
   Whenever I select a cell in tbl_1Main, the row of the selected cell is highlighted. 
   It doesn’t work without the “Application.ScreenUpdating = True” code.
3. In the 2 procedures I have 2 lines of code.
   If there was lengthy code I would use retailcoder’s suggestion of each module calling the generic code from another module.
   But otherwise the suggestions seem a bit complicated. As David Zemens noted “… Sounds like what OP wants to avoid is having three different Click handlers for the button, and 3 different _Change handlers for the Worksheet objects.”

I was hoping that the Click handler could access generic code. Unfortunately as retailcoder points out: “… if there's a button on Sheet1 its Click handler belongs in the code of Sheet1….”

So many thanks for making the effort to try and solve my problem.
Regards, huon

Comment: Do you have a `cmdGrabTable` button on all 3 sheets?

Comment: `SelectionChange` event would get called *every time* the user clicks on an unselected cell, so that would be *quite often*; careful what you put in there. `Application.ScreenUpdating` doesn't need to be set that often (and it's *true* by default) because you'll only want to set it to *false* when you're doing stuff that would otherwise make Excel flicker; you'd set it back to false after you're done with the hard work, ..not everytime the user selects a new cell. That's why my answer only addresses the `Click` handler.

Comment: I moved the Worksheet_SelectionChange procedure into a module and made it public. As David Zemens predicted, it didn't work; which seems logical as it is a worksheet event. Huon

Comment: To use worksheet events in a code module you need to declare a `Worksheet` variable using `WithEvents`. You can assign that worksheet variable to point to any sheet if you want. My suggestion was to use the worksheets you already have and write your code in one place, in a way that allows you to pass any parameters you might need. I don't see a simpler way.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me using a Workbook event.  It's a pretty simple example, but hopefully you get the idea:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

With Sh
    If .Name = "Sheet1" Or .Name = "Sheet2" Then
        MsgBox ("You made a change on " & .Name)
    Else
        MsgBox ("You didn't make a change on either Sheet1 or Sheet2, but on " & .Name)
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Also, you can wire up your buttons so that they all execute the same code by utilizing a Class.

1) Add a reference to Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library (Tools -> References)

2) Add a Class to your project.

3) Add the following code to the class module:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents mbutton As MSForms.CommandButton
Public Property Set Control(obtNew As MSForms.CommandButton)
    Set mbutton = obtNew
End Property

Private Sub mbutton_Click()
MsgBox ("Generic Message goes here!")
End Sub
```

4) Add a regular module to your class and add the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim mcolEvents As Collection

Sub InitializeEvents()
    Dim obtButton As OLEObject
    Dim clsEvents As Class1

    If mcolEvents Is Nothing Then
        Set mcolEvents = New Collection
    End If

    For Each obtButton In Sheet1.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(obtButton.Object) = "CommandButton" Then
            Set clsEvents = New Class1
            Set clsEvents.Control = obtButton.Object
            mcolEvents.Add clsEvents
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

5) Add a few Active X buttons to sheet 1 and run the InitializeEvents() code.

6) Press any of the buttons you've added to your sheet

7) Modify code to suit your specific scenario

8) ...

9) Profit!

Keep in mind, this is a simple example, but should get you going down the right path.  Basically, you need to add the buttons you want to execute the specific code to the mcolEvents collection and you're all set.

Good luck and feel free to post back should you need any help.

Comment: +1 for using `WithEvents`. Clever. But things can get messy in the `For Each` loop if there's *ever* a need to add buttons that would behave differently. If two buttons do the same thing but act upon a different range (one selects range A, the other selects range B - both just select a range), everything in the "wrapper class" click handler must be hard-coded in a nice `if` block, there's no way to pass a paremeter here to say "select range X for me"... this isn't .NET! But yeah, if all buttons on a worksheet need to do the *exact same thing*, this is totally it. Well done!

Comment: @retailcoder Thanks!  Yes, I agree it could get cluttered.  Taking the code as I've written it could get messy.  But rather than just adding in any "CommandButton" you could use another property (like the .Name) and name the controls something similar so that only buttons with a .name starting with "CustomClick" would get applied (completely trying to remember how I did it, so not tested at all).  In all honesty, I would do it the way you've outlined...but it's always nice to throw out another way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

To use a piece of code in more than one worksheet you could put it in a *code module* (.bas) and have the *shared* code be `Public`. If a procedure is `Private`, only the code within that module can "see" it.

```
Public Sub SomeSharedCode(ByVal TheRange As Range)
    'do something with TheRange
End Sub
```

Unfortunately you can't tell a button to be handled by code that can't see the button - in other words if there's a button on Sheet1 its `Click` handler belongs in the code of `Sheet1`. What you *can* do is have all those handlers call the same code, like this:

In Sheet1:

```
Private Sub Sheet1CmdGrabTable_Click()
    SomeSharedCode Range("tbl_1Main")
End Sub
```

In Sheet2:

```
Private Sub Sheet2CmdGrabTable_Click()
    SomeSharedCode Range("tbl_2Main")
End Sub
```

In Sheet3:

```
Private Sub Sheet3CmdGrabTable_Click()
    SomeSharedCode Range("tbl_3Main")
End Sub
```

Comment: Pretty sure this doesn't work for application `Event` procedures (i.e., you can't put the button `Click` event in a public code module, nor can you put the worksheet `Change` event in a public module).  Sounds like what OP wants to avoid is having three different `Click` handlers for the button, and 3 different `_Change` handlers for the Worksheet objects.

Comment: @DavidZemens edited to clarify. Worksheet events must be handled in that worksheet's "code-behind" of course.

Comment: @retailcoder for what it's worth, I've mocked up an example in my answer using a class.  Seems to do what the OP was asking. It uses a single click event set @ the class level and you can subscribe whichever buttons you want to that click event.